# Adding scores of sentences depending on region Python very lost

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a txt file containing over 200 tweets and **im trying to calculate total scores** for **all the tweets in a particular region** given their long/ lat.. a typical tweet looks like:

```
[30.346168930000001, -97.73518] 0 2011-08-29 04:54:22 Best vacation of my life #byfar
```

Ive done this before, but only calculating for the line of the sentence, so I did**Side note, I have a file containing words, and another containing sentences and I had to see if any of the words are in the sentences and add the amount of words and their sentiment value which was a value associated with the word.. looked like**

```
Happy: 1
Sad, 5:

with open('words.txt') as f:
    sentiments = {word: int(value)
                 for word, value in
                 (line.split(",") for line in f)}

with open('sentences.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        values = Counter(word for word in line.split() if word in sentiments)
        if not values:
            continue
```

But the whole long, lat business, I dont know how to add all the scores in a particular region. Mostly because im confused about the longitiude and latititude.

So, first I tried to "approximate" regions corresponding to their timezones (not real data). So **Eastern (P1. P2. P3, P4**, **Pacific(P7, P8, P9, P10)**, **Mountain (P5, P6, P7, P8)** , **Central(P3,P4,P5,P6)**..

So with this info:

```
p1 = (49.189787, -67.444574) 
p2 = (24.660845, -67.444574)
p3 = (49.189787, -87.518395) 
p4 = (24.660845, -87.518395) 
p5 = (49.189787, -101.998892)
p6 = (24.660845, -101.998892) 
p7 = (49.189787, -115.236428) 
p8 = (24.660845, -115.236428) 
p9 = (49.189787, -125.242264)
p10 = (24.660845, -125.242264)
```

I determined the regions as

```
class Region:
    def __init__(self, lat_tuple, long_tuple):
        self.lat_tuple = lat_tuple
        self.long_tuple = long_tuple

    def contains(self, lat, long):
        return self.lat_tuple[0] <= lat and lat < self.lat_tuple[1] and\
               self.long_tuple[0] <= long and long < self.long_tuple[1]

 eastern = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-87.518395, -67.444574))
 central = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-101.998892, -87.518395))
 mountain = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-115.236428, -101.998892))
 pacific = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-125.242264, -115.236428))
```

I think I have gotten most of it done but I just dont know how to say if the tweets are in the. I need help adding up all the scores of sentences in a particular region. Or just an outline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't check you're coordinates completely, but you seem to be on the right track. Using what you did, all I would need to do to parse the tweet file:

```
scores = {'eastern':0,'central':0,'pacific':0,'mountain':0}
for line in open('tweets.txt'):
    line = line.split(" ")
    lat  = float(line[0][1:-1]) #Stripping the [ and the ,
    long = float(line[1][:-1])  #Stripping the ]
    if eastern.contains(lat,long):
         scores['eastern'] += score(line) #Assuming you have a score function
    elif central.contains(lat,long):
         scores['central'] += score(line)         
    elif mountain.contains(lat,long):
         scores['mountain'] += score(line)
    elif pacific.contains(lat,long):
         scores['pacific'] += score(line)
    else: raise ValueError("Could not locate coordinates "+line[0]+line[1])
```

You could make this more elegant by wrapping the `if` statements in a function:

```
def region(lat,long):
    #DEFINE HERE YOUR REGIONS, IN THE Function, or leave them as globals
    if eastern.contains(lat,long):  return 'eastern'
    if central.contains(lat,long):  return 'central'         
    if mountain.contains(lat,long): return 'mountain'
    if pacific.contains(lat,long):  return 'pacific'
    raise ValueError(" ".join(("could not locate coordinates",str(lat),str(long))))
```

Than the if statements in the loop are gone:

```
scores[region(lat,long)] += score(line)
```

EDIT:
you need to define score to be a function that accepts a tweet, or the split line in my above code(which is a list of words, including the coordinate):

```
def score(tweet):
    total = 0
    for word in tweet:
        if word in sentiments: total += 1
    return total/(len(tweet)-2) #Subtract the coordinates from the length)
```

Assuming the global `sentiments` is defined beforehand.

Comment: Thank you! Ive accepted your method. Im trying it out now.  Does this allow me to count/total the amount of tweets in each region?

Comment: It should, you can easily use this in multiple ways.

Comment: The score for the individual tweet is the total of the “sentiment values” divided by the number of keywords found( which is score_tweet in my program). And then the score for a timezone is just the total of the scores for all the tweets in that region divided by the number of tweets. I see where I got confused, Where you said "score" and #Assuming I have a function, to calculate the scores for the tweets I just did score_Tweet = (sum(values[word]*sentiments[word] for word in values)) // (len(values)) but when I change your "score" to my "score_tweet" i get a TypeError:

Comment: "'int' object is not callable"

Comment: I wasn't sure what 'values' is in your comment, but I edited to give an example of score (note scores is a dict and score is a function). You can amend it however you like, or use Counter like in your question.

Comment: true! I was thinking of using the counter.. Thank you so much!

Comment: I changed raise ValueError to what I have in my edit, so that if a tweet is out of the range of the long, lat, it is ignored. Does that word (above)?

Comment: Just omit that entire line, or use 'print' to see what's skipped.

Comment: Ok! Yes It works perfectly thanks! One more question sorry and then Ill leave you to be lol  can you look at how I inputed (above) the longitude and lat numbers for each region?? Just because the # of tweets im getting for each region is high so I wanted to know if I inputed it properly

Comment: You see how I got the values from the tweets?? How would I be able to find out which region those values are from, and add all the values from the specific region? Ive tried like 20 different methods but it keeps saying its not defined

Comment: This is getting to be a bit of a discussion. Please ask a new question, and write your new code to see how someone can help - currently I don't know what you have. Write a complete and minimal example of the new code and the error. You can link to it in the comments here and I'll take a look if no one doesn't answer before.

Comment: Sorry! Just have an hour 15 mins to complete this and my stupid instructor hasnt replied to any of my emails for the past 24 hours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644895/adding-scores-depending-on-their-regions-long-latitude-in-python-asisstance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650483/very-long-python-2-part-how-to-focus-on-specific-lines-in-a-file-how-to-add @kabanus